# Printing attribute in pre & post link in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access and print class names in angular directives. But, I am not getting desired result. Instead, getting undefined for all values.

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
return{
 template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
 compile:function(elem, attr){
  console.log("compile");
  return{
   pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("pre"+ this.class) ;
   },
   post:function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("post"+ this.class);
   }     
  }
 },
}
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<my-student class="one"></my-student> 
<my-student class="two"></my-student> 
<my-student class="three"></my-student> 
<my-student class="four"></my-student> 
<my-student class="five"></my-student> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: mat i know what is the expected output intsead of undefined?

Comment: one, two, three, four, five

Comment: Why are you not using attr to fetch arributes instead of this??

Comment: Ok. I thought 'this' should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

then try  with using **attr.class**

```
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
return{
    template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
    compile:function(elem, attr){
        console.log("compile");
        return{
            pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                console.log("pre"+ attr.class) ;
            },
            post:function(scope,elem,attr){
                console.log("post"+attr.class);
            }                   
        }
    },
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`elem`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) or `attr` argument of the link function.
Note, that `elem.attr('class')` will give you the actual listt of classes, including the classes added by angular like `ng-binding`. `attr['class']` will give you the original "one", "two" ...

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
return{
 template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
 compile:function(elem, attr){
  console.log("compile");
  return{
   pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("pre"+ elem.attr('class')) ;
   },
   post:function(scope,elem,attr){
    console.log("post"+ attr['class']);
   }     
  }
 },
}
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<my-student class="one"></my-student> 
<my-student class="two"></my-student> 
<my-student class="three"></my-student> 
<my-student class="four"></my-student> 
<my-student class="five"></my-student> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Comment: I think, you could also use the attr object directly from the arguments. instead of using elem.attr